# Parsing Text with Conditional Regular Expressions in VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba, vbscript, regex-negation

I'm parsing large amounts of textual data using Regular Expressions in VBA within cells of an Excel document using Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5.

I can't figure out how to create a Regular Expression phrase that WILL match something that reads: "deploy", "deploying", "deployment" but NOT something that says specifically "redeploy". So far I've tried the below expressions, to no avail:

```
(^[rR][eE])([dD][eE][pP][lL][oO][yY])
(^[rR][eE])?([dD][eE][pP][lL][oO][yY])
.(^[rR][eE])([dD][eE][pP][lL][oO][yY])
*(^[rR][eE])([dD][eE][pP][lL][oO][yY])
```

Could anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Or is this not possible given how Regex functions?

Comment: Basically, you want to match *deploy*, but not words containing *deploy* ?

Comment: `"\bdeploy\b"` matches the word exactly by requiring it be surrounded by boundaries if that's what your asking.  Also `YourRegExp.IgnoreCase = True`

Comment: I'm looking to specifically exclude "redeploy". I would include "deploying", "deployment", etc. I apologize for the lack of clarity, OP has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"(?!re)\b\S*deploy\S*"
```

will not match redeploy, but would match, for example misdeploy, as well as the various forms (deployment, deploying, etc)

If you can eliminate all the words that "prefix" deploy, then

```
"\bdeploy\S*"
```

would be simpler.

Comment: This is perfect, and looks to be supported by VB. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :
`redeploy\w*|(\w*deploy\w*)`
The words you are looking for are in the first capturing group. It will capture every words containing *deploy* but not beginning with *redeploy*.
You can also try the code below (not tested) :

```
Dim searchStr As String
searchStr = "redeploy deploying redeployment deploy"
Dim regex As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim matches
regex.Pattern = "redeploy\w*|(\w*deploy\w*)"
regex.IgnoreCase = True
regex.Global = True
If regex.test(searchStr) Then
    Set matches = regex.Execute(searchStr)
    Dim match As Variant
    For Each match In matches
        Debug.Print match.Submatches(0)
    Next
End If
```

Comment: I'm looking to specifically exclude "redeploy". I would include "deploying", "deployment", etc. I apologize for the lack of clarity, OP has been updated.

Comment: VBA/VBScript does NOT support mode modification tokens within the regex.

Comment: @Alex: I edited my answer, tell me if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.IgnoreCase = True
>> r.Pattern = "\bdeploy"
>> For Each w In Split("redeploy deploy deploywhatever misdeploy")
>>     WScript.Echo w, CStr(r.Test(w))
>> Next
>>
redeploy Falsch
deploy Wahr
deploywhatever Wahr
misdeploy Falsch
>>
```

to try if "a word starting with 'deploy'" meets your spec.